# Is Spring mongoTemplate thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, spring-mongo

I define this Bean:

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mongoConverter" />
</bean>
```

and i instantiate a `mongoOprations` using this Bean, now i want To know Is Spring `mongoTemplate` thread safe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per spring docs.

> Once configured, MongoTemplate is thread-safe and can be reused across
>   multiple instances.

For more details see section [5.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/)